# How to run an exe first then wait 5 seconds and then run another exe in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off

Start C:\a.exe
SLEEP 5
Start C:\b.exe
Start C:\c.exe
```

I am using windows 10 64 bit. What I am trying to do is to run a.exe first. and then wait 5 seconds and run b and c simultaneously. But they all start running at the same time

Comment: Change `SLEEP 5` to `Timeout /T 5 /NoBreak>NUL`. Also you may not need to use `Start` on your last line, but as we know nothing about your executables, only you could know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SLEEP` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Try `TIMEOUT /T 5 >NUL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Powershell.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
& "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.5\bin\pycharm.exe"
```

Just as an example

Hope it helps! BR